# Firebase not save the data in firestore cloud database

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I want to store data on firestore cloud database in react native application.

But when I click on signup button its give me this error.

My firestore is in test mode i also do this on production mode but not worked.

Code:

```
const signinwithemailandpass =async (email, pass) => {
    console.log("new",selecteduser);
    const data = await addDoc(collection(db, "signupauth"), {
        email: email,
        register: selecteduser,
    });
    console.log(data.id);
}
```

Prints:

[image: here is my firestore ruues]

[image]

Please, I need help to resove this error, I was stick on this past two days.

Answer (score 0):

The error notice suggests that the authentication credentials you're using to access the Firestore database may be problematic. Make sure Firebase has been properly initialized, that the required authentication methods are enabled, and that your React Native application is utilizing the appropriate authentication credentials. Make that your Firestore rules permit both read and write access to the pertinent collections, and think about turning on debug logging to learn more about the error. Ask for more assistance from a knowledgeable Google Cloud support if the problem continues.